# Have actual but duplicate data in table or reference its id and run two queries or a more complex query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

[image]

Given the previous tables, i am selecting names of kids and their favorite quotes.  In terms of speed, efficiency, and database design best practices, which is better?  Should i have the actual quote in table `kids` or should i not have the actual quote but reference its id then do another query to fetch it from `quotes` table?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I find it easier to use ID's, pretty much whenever possible. Imagine needing to change a Lincoln quote and having to disable the foreign keys to do it. Then, when you've updated the quotes table, having to update and re-enable the key on the kids table... I've dealt with that in a legacy system, and I wanted to scream.

But that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather go with the quote's reference id than duplicating the `favorite_quote` field.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a waste of space to duplicate what appears to be a thousand+ length varchar field more than once.

Normalization of this structure wouldn't really affect performance, **and it may actually speed up queries**: those very long quotes are going to cause all kinds of page fragmentation in your `kids` table.

Keeping a separate `quote` table will make it easier to manage and perform better overall.

EDIT:

To answer the question in the comment, you need a `quote_id` field in `Kids` to `JOIN` on:

```
SELECT k.Name, q.Favorite_Quote
FROM kids k
LEFT JOIN quotes q
    ON q.id = k.quote_id
```

Comment: How would i use a JOIN  if i want to select a name from kids and the quote from quotes?

Comment: Replacing strings with ID numbers might or might not speed up SELECT queries. But replacing strings with ID numbers has absolutely nothing to do with normalization.

Answer (score -1):

For me it depends on how the data is being used.

For example if the information is needed on each page like

> Hey Timmy, we see you're still 8 and your favorite quote is "Action is the blah blah blah"

Then I would go for a single query, but, if the information was only going to be used on a specific page or you want say a quotes page then use multiple queries.

I hope this helps.

Comment: That depends on the design of your application, I have seen applications so clearly defined by functions that joining to a single query no longer worked, the required information to construct a query wasn't able to be passed so some applications will run multiple queries to achieve their goals. I have to take what the author has asked and respond in kind or the answer may not actually be correct depending on the information that has not been shared

Comment: OK, well, he's showing a table structure that pretty clearly includes a lookup table for the quote, and retrieving that information in relation to the `kids` table necessitates a join.

Comment: Understood what you're saying but if I only need the information from the kids table why would I create a join to the quotes table for information I already have? In saying that if I'm only using the quotes information on a page why would I join the kids table? Also, if I have just 1 single record from the kids table but I want all records from the quotes table then again I don't see why a join will be appropriate.

Comment: How would i use a JOIN  if i want to select a name from kids and the quote from quotes?

Comment: Exactly, you see my point then? It depends on the usage of the data as to the design of your database and how you're going to access the information ;-)

Comment: @Ryan - not to be rude but I'm not sure you know what you are talking about.  You are constructing strawman arguments.  In both your scenarios it would still be faster to have the data in two tables instead of one.

Comment: @JNK I understand what you're saying but the problem is you're assuming you know the rest of the code before answering, I'm allowing for the fact that data is used in a variety of ways and not all together in the same instance, I'm also allowing for circumstances where a single query is not viable. Best practice would say have 1 table for each type of data, practically this is not always viable depending on the rest of the application and how you want to use the data in the application. I have been working with PHP and mySQL for 11 years so I know a thing or 2 about it

Comment: @Ryan - we will have to agree to disagree then

Comment: Not to be dense here or anything but it's sounding like you're saying that the application architecture should not be an influencing factor in how to structure your database? And are you saying that you must pull all data from a database even if that data is not required? How is using a join to get information that is not required going to speed up your query?

Comment: @Ryan - you are being a little dense.  You have two (related) tables - if you just need data from one, it's less work for SQL to pull from a single narrow table instead of a single WIDE table.  If you need data from both you use a `JOIN`.  In either case it is likely faster on the DB side to have normalized data than to denormalize and store a long string multiple times.

Comment: Of course I have been a little defensive, look at your insulting message previously. This is beside the point, look at what I said, if you don't need the data then why do a join to get data you wont use? The table already has the quote and information needed, if you were to need this on every page then it makes no sense to have to do a join, use a single table. On the other hand if the quote information is seldom required then put it in a separate table and use a join if and when needed. At times a single query is not possible.